# Using PPT VPV on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, vpn

I'm using windows 8 and some services aren't available in my country, so I have to use a virtual private network. When I try to connect with PPTP VPN, after connection there is a yellow mark on my network icon in tray which says

```
no internet connection
```

or sometimes

```
limited connection
```

I tried to solve the problem by un-checking the "use default gateway" in ipv4 advanced option and after that yellow mark was gone, but the problem still exist and I can't go to store or open some sites. It's like I don't have a VPN connection at all, my router is set to VPN through and everything seems to be fine. Does anybody know what's wrong with windows 8 and VPN? never had this problems in Windows 7.

Comment: I assume this VPN used to work?

Comment: in windows 8 never but in windows 7 two days ago before i move on to windows 8 it was working like a bebe :D

Comment: Well there were no changes betwen Windows 8 and Windows 7 with this regard.  So that only leaves to a configuration problem.